# Вставить директиву в колонку таблицы AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется компонент таблицы, который принимает названия колонок и строки с данными, которые нужно отобразить в таблице. Но не всегда данные - это текст. Иногда хочется добавить собственную директиву.

Например, имеется некий контроллер со своим шаблоном, в котором я хочу добавить свой компонент-таблицу. В контроллере я задаю данные, которые хочу передать в таблицу:

```
ctrl.tableData = [
  { name: 'Alex', age: '34', mobile: '<my-directive ng-model="ctrl.mobile">' }
];
```

Затем в шаблоне я отправляю эти данные в таблицу:

```
<my-table-component data="ctrl.tableData"></my-table-component>
```

Ну и в самом компоненте `my-table-component` отрисовывается таблица:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.data">
    <td ng-repeat="column in ctrl.columns">{{ row[column] }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

С такой реализацией таблицы, я не смогу вставить директиву, поскольку она вставиться просто текстом. Для этого я создал доп. директиву, которая компилирует директивы. Пусть ее название будет `my-table-directive`. Делает она следующее:

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
  const columnElem = angular.element(element);

  let columnChild = attrs.columnValue;

  if (attrs.columnValue.startsWith('<')) {
    columnChild = $compile(columnChild)(scope);
  }

  columnElem.append(columnChild);
}
```

И мой шаблон таблицы немного видоизменился:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in ctrl.columns">
    column-value={{row[column]}}
    my-table-directive></td>
```

Все вроде как окей. Но проблема в том, что компилируется директива совсем не с тем скоупом, который ожидается :)
Естественно, я хочу менять свойство `mobile` в моем самом верхнем скоупе, где я задавал `ctrl.tableData`. А с текущей реализацией `ng-model` директивы `my-directive` будет писать данные в свойство `mobile` скоупа моего `<td>` в таблице.

Может быть, мое решение не совсем правильное? Может можно как-то по-другому организовать вставку директив в компоненте-таблице? Задача кажется популярной, однако ничего не получилось нагуглить. Помагите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Я бы советовал все же не заниматься такими вещами, а в шаблоне вашей таблицы просто прописать все директивы. Потом их по `ng-if` показывать\прятать. Так код получится чище, нагляднее, проще в поддержке.